# What type of neural network should I be using to generate a paragraph based on some input?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, nlp

My knowledge of neural networks is very basic but here is my goal:
Given a set of short inputs (One word strings and numbers) I want the trained network to generate a paragraph of text related to the input data.

I've messed with RNNs before to do basic natural language generation but never based on a given input.
(I played around with https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn for example)

There is so much information out there I'm not sure what sort of model I should be using or where to start.

Comment: You need to read more about NNs. I would suggest to start from MLP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is too broad to answer in a single answer, but I tried to mention a few things that will be helpful to continue your research on this area.

*What is text-generation?*

The problem you mentioned is mainly recognized as **text-generation** in literature. Given a piece of text (e.g., a sequence of characters, words or paragraphs) to the model, the model tries to complete, rest of the text. The better your model is, the better *semantically* and *syntactically* structure of the generated text will be.

Text Generation itself is a type of [Language Modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model) problem. Language Modelling is the core problem for many natural language processing (NLP). A trained language model learns the likelihood of occurrence of a word based on the previous sequence of words used in the text. What does it mean? For instance, in the sentence: `A cat sits on the ...`, the probability that the next word will be `mat` is larger than to be `water`. This simple idea is the main intuition behind language modeling. See [chapter 4 of this book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/ed3book.pdf) for a thorough explanation on this topic.

*Different kinds of language modeling:*

Different kinds of approach are proposed for language modeling which mostly categorized into **Statistical** and **Neural** language model. For a comparison between these two approaches take a look into [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/statistical-language-modeling-and-neural-language-models/) blog post.

Recently, the use of neural networks in the development of language models has become the dominant way because:

> Nonlinear neural network models solve some of the shortcomings of
> traditional language models: they allow conditioning on increasingly
> large context sizes with only a linear increase in the number of
> parameters, they alleviate the need for manually designing backoff
> orders, and they support generalization across different contexts.
>
> Page 109, Neural Network Methods in Natural Language Processing,
> 2017.

*Different kinds of Neural Network for language modeling:*

A bunch of Neural Networks architecture proposed for language modeling using: [recurrent neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network), [feedforward neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedforward_neural_network), [convolution neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network), etc. which have their own pros and cons. According to [here](http://nlpprogress.com/english/language_modeling.html) the state-of-the-art benchmark achieved by RNN models.

RNNs are called recurrent because they perform the same task for every element of a sequence, with the output being depended on the previous computations. Another way to think about RNNs is that they have a “memory” which captures information about what has been calculated so far. Visit [here](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-1-introduction-to-rnns/) for further details on RNN.

*How to implement RNN for text-generation?*

See official example in Tensrflow [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/text_generation).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to start with some toy samples, like:

- https://medium.com/phrasee/neural-text-generation-generating-text-using-conditional-language-models-a37b69c7cd4b
- https://machinelearningmastery.com/text-generation-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

Natural text generation is a complex task. It can be done with N_gram appoach, RNN networks (as you mentioned), the way how it can be done you may find by links above.